# Which is correct, "voicemail box" or "voice mailbox"

Tags: portmanteau-words

At work, I commonly type "voicemail box" and "voice mailbox" interchangeably so I'm wrong only half the time. Which one is correct?

I had a similar dilemma with "login to" and "log into", but this site has satisfied my curiosity by suggesting "log in to". I'm begrudgingly ready to create my own portmanteaus "loginto" and "voicemailbox".

Comment: These terms are new and evolving.  I think with a search you will find other questions and answers in relation to log in and login.  However, with respect to voicemail box and voice mailbox, I would prefer the first, but I concede I have no hard evidence to support that decision. Perhaps it needs to be three word "voice mail box" - or better, don't run the three "new" words together at all. So you simply say either "voicemail" or "mailbox".

Comment: Like @Cargill, I don't think we'll be able to point to a corpus as evidence of one being more "correct" than the other; for such evolving terms, the English-speaking community will eventually coalesce on one "correct" term, but we're not there yet. I would think that the tie between "mail" and "box" is more important (stronger) than the tie between "voice" and "mail," on the grounds that a "mail box" for "voicemail" is not in fact a "box" at all, but "voicemail" is in fact "voice mail." Thus I would prefer "voice mailbox." But, likely, neither is wrong.

Comment: I do lean more towards "voice mailbox" because it sounds like "voice" is describing the type of "mailbox"

Comment: Voicemail mailbox is probably the most "correct", so I'm leaning towards voice mailbox as a good contraction of sorts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types of compound nouns.

> 1. open or spaced - space between words (tennis shoe)
> 2. hyphenated - hyphen between words (six-pack)
> 3. closed or solid - no space or hyphen between words (bedroom)

Even though [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voicemail) posted *voice mail* as a *closed compound noun* (still *voice mail system* is an open compound noun there) and you get more google hits for *voicemail* (18.1 million) than *voice mail* (9.9 million), this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voice+mail%2C+voicemail&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvoice%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoicemail%3B%2Cc0) favors *voice mail* over *voicemail*. Also, another [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voicemail+box%2C+voice+mailbox%2C+voice+mail+box&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvoicemail%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoice%20mailbox%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoice%20mail%20box%3B%2Cc0) records more of ***voice mailbox*** or ***voice mail box*** than *voicemail box*.

As the two Ngram Viewers show, people started to use the words around year 1980 and as commented above, it is difficult to say which is correct. But, *voice mailbox* is the one which is favored.

Answer (score 1):

Between "voicemail box" and "voice mailbox", there's seems to be slight preference for the former, but definitely not enough that the latter can be considered incorrect.

I looked at the websites for several phone/voice companies and found:

- [AT&T](https://www.att.com/support/article/wireless/KM1008685/): voicemail box
- [Mitel](https://oneview.mitel.com/s/article/Voicemail-Box?language=en_US): voicemail box
- [T-Mobile](https://www.sprint.com/en/support/solutions/services/know-how-many-messages-can-be-stored-in-your-voicemail-box.html): voicemail box, mailbox
- [Google Phone app](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/2811844): voice mailbox
- [Xfinity](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/setting-up-voicemail): voice mailbox, mailbox
- Verizon ([Voicemail FAQs](https://www.verizon.com/support/voice-mail-faqs/), [Retrieve Voicemail Messages](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-17379/), [Hosted Voice Messaging Service (Voice-mail)](https://www.verizon.com/business/service_guide/reg/cp_hosted_voice_messaging_-_voicemail.htm)): voicemail box, voice mailbox, voice-mail box, voicemail mailbox
- [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/set-up-phone-system-voicemail): voicemail mailbox (but "mailbox" means email)

All of them use "voicemail" by itself also to refer to the box.

Note: The all-open spelling "voice mail box" seems to be predominantly used by the [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/03/business/phone-ringless-voicemail-fcc-telemarketer.html) (and other US news sources), which [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/spelling/voicemail/) calls "editorially conservative". But Microsoft also has one instance of "voice mail" among their other instances of "voicemail", so there's not always consistency.

Answer (score 0):

This one has nagged at me for years. After reading this post I have decided to change "voicemail" to "vmail". Now the "box" does not seem necessary.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416566)

Answer (score -1):

'voicemail mailbox' might be the most correct, but I assume no one will start using it any time soon.

I like 'voicemailbox'; hopefully that's where we'll end up in 10 years.